# Convert a combination of two data structures to a specific JSON object

Tags: json, r, list, lapply

Assume you have the following data:

```
obj1 <- list('A', 'B', c('A', 'B'))
obj2 <- rep(1, 3)
```

The resulting JSON object I need, which is a combination of both, looks like this:

```
[{'obj1':['A'], 'obj2':[1]},{'obj1':['B'], 'obj2':[1]}, {'obj1':['A','B'], 'obj2':[1]}]
```

Notice, that even single elements like `A` are embraced in square brackets!

My question now is, whats the easiest way to generate this JSON structure? `obj1` and `obj2` do not have to be lists or vectors. It could also be a single dataframe. The important thing is the structure of the final JSON output.

My attempt so far is

```
tmp <- lapply(obj1, FUN = function(x) { 
  x <- list("obj1" = x)
  x$obj2 <- obj2[1]
  obj2  <<- obj2[-1]
  return(x)
})
jsonlite::toJSON(tmp)
```

which does work. It just does not seem to be the best attempt.

Comment: The values in `obj2` are all 1s, but in your example output are 10, 10, 0.5. Was that intentional? (I'm guessing not).

Comment: Nope it was not. My mistake. Sorry. Edits are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
df <- data.frame(obj1 = I(obj1), obj2 = I(as.list(obj2)))
toJSON(df)
# [{"obj1":["A"],"obj2":[1]},{"obj1":["B"],"obj2":[1]},{"obj1":["A","B"],"obj2":[1]}]

jsonlite::toJSON(tmp)
# [{"obj1":["A"],"obj2":[1]},{"obj1":["B"],"obj2":[1]},{"obj1":["A","B"],"obj2":[1]}]
```

---

The key points here are

- Using `I()` to ensure the column types are `list`
- The columns in `df` need to be named appropriately (`obj1` and `obj2`)
- `obj2` needs to be coerced to `list` also (`as.list(obj2)`) in order to get, e.g. `"obj2":[1]` instead of `"obj2":1`

I determined this by reverse engineering your desired output:

```
json <- gsub(
    "'", '"', 
    "[{'obj1':['A'],'obj2':[1]},{'obj1':['B'],'obj2':[1]},{'obj1':['A','B'],'obj2':[1]}]"
)
str(fromJSON(json))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ obj1:List of 3
#   ..$ : chr "A"
#   ..$ : chr "B"
#   ..$ : chr  "A" "B"
#  $ obj2:List of 3
#   ..$ : int 1
#   ..$ : int 1
#   ..$ : int 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats looks way better than my first approach. I will give this a little more time though :)